# Primeng datatable, make header and footer identical?

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a PrimeNg dataTable like this:

```
<p-dataTable>
    <p-header> [A bunch of stuff] </p-header>
    <p-footer> [The same stuff as in the header] </p-footer>
    <p-column>...</p-column>
    <p-column>...</p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

I'm interested in writing the code for the header and footer only one time. For instance, create a separate template containing that code,  and then the header and footer each call that template.

Is there an easy way to do this?  I tried using ng-template but I couldn't get it to work.  I'm an Angular newbie..

Answer (score 0):

You could put the 'stuff' in a string variable or property in the component and use {{interpolation}} to show it in the markup.